# Django Rest Framework | Foreign key object not saving

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

Whenever I make POST request to my django app , it throws an error

```
'Genre' instance expected, got (<Genre: Adventure>, False)
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening.Please help with the serializer. My Movie object is getting saved but the Genre objects is not because of this error.

**Model**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField()
    director = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    imdb_score = models.FloatField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Genre(models.Model):
    name =  models.ForeignKey(Movie,related_name='genres',blank=True, null=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.genre)
```

**Serializer**

```
class CreatableSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**{self.slug_field: data})
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', slug_name=self.slug_field, value=smart_text(data))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')

class MovieSerializer5(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genres = CreatableSlugRelatedField(many=True,slug_field='genre',queryset=Genre.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('popularity', 'director','imdb_score', 'name', 'genres')
```

**View**

```
class MovieList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return Response("User is not permitted this action")

        serializer = MovieSerializer5(data=request.data)
        print serializer.initial_data
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: so did we solved your question? what about some points? ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the helper `get_or_create` it returns a tuple with the object (created or not), and a boolean that indicates you if the object was created or it was already on the db, watch out with that ;)

Answer (score 0):

get_or_create returns a tuple of (object, created), so in to_internal_value on your serializer, you need something like:

```
return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**{self.slug_field: data})[0]
```

to access the object that was created or retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to return only the created object.**

[`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) actually returns a tuple of `(object, created)`, where `object` is the retrieved or created object and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

You can do something like:

```
obj, created = self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**{self.slug_field: data})
return obj # return the created object
```